# How I install repository in Go when i have the next trouble "no required module provides package"?

Tags: go, github

im new in Go and i can't install the next repository in git:https://github.com/westphae/geomag. This repo has written in Go.

I have the next trouble:

```
    (base) soporte@CI-93:~/geomag/cmd/wmm_point$ go build main.go
main.go:81:2: no required module provides package github.com/westphae/geomag/internal/util; to add it:
    go get github.com/westphae/geomag/internal/util
main.go:82:2: no required module provides package github.com/westphae/geomag/pkg/egm96; to add it:
    go get github.com/westphae/geomag/pkg/egm96
main.go:83:2: no required module provides package github.com/westphae/geomag/pkg/wmm; to add it:
    go get github.com/westphae/geomag/pkg/wmm
(base) soporte@CI-93:~/geomag/cmd/wmm_point$ go get github.com/westphae/geomag/internal/util
go get github.com/westphae/geomag/internal/util: no matching versions for query "upgrade"
```

Thanks

Comment: Dont use filename arguments with go build. Use modules.

Comment: Can you give me how install it step for step?

Comment: Did you try the instructions in the error message? Did you setup your model as described in the Getting Started docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you give me how install it step for step?

The project you are trying to install does not utilise [go modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules). If you run `go build` you will receive instructions covering how to rectify this. In short:

```
$ cd geomag
/geomag$ go mod init github.com/westphae/geomag
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/westphae/geomag
go: to add module requirements and sums:
        go mod tidy
/geomag$ go mod tidy
/geomag$ cd cmd/wmm_point
/geomag/cmd/wmm_point$ go build
/geomag/cmd/wmm_point$ ./wmm_point.exe
COF File: WMM-2020, Epoch: 2020, Valid Date: 12/10/2019
Please enter latitude North Latitude positive. For example: 30, 30, 30 (D,M,S) or 30.508 (Decimal Degrees) (both are north).  is not in the format D M S
```

(there are other approaches but this is probably the simplest for someone new to the language).